# The results could not be loaded when searching for users

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I need to implement select2 with ajax, and I'm using [this](https://github.com/NeilMeredith/Select2Demo/blob/master/Select2Demo/Views/Home/Index.cshtml) as an example project to work from.

This is what I have so far

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="js-data-example-ajax form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
        placeholder: 'Enter name',
        //Does the user have to enter any data before sending the ajax request
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            quietMillis: 150,
            // url: '@Url.Action("GetUsers", "CRMTItems")',
            url: '/CRMTItems/GetUsers/' + $('.js-data-example-ajax').text(),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            results: function (data) {
                console.log('results');
                return { results: data.results }
            }
            // Additional AJAX parameters go here; see the end of this chapter for the full code of this example
        }
    });
)};
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetUsers(string term)
{
    var users = CRMTItemViewModel.AllUsers.Where(u => u.DisplayName.Contains(term));
    var userList = AttendeesToSelect2Format(users, 10);
    return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I can see that the search term is passed in and the data is filtered, but when it gets sent back to the view I just see

[image]

I tried copying the sample project exactly, but then I ran into further issues:

1. When using `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `<select>` I just see

   > No select2/compat/inputData

   in the js console
2. When copying the js exactly (with the `data` and `results` function), my search term never makes it to the controller, and `null` is passed in every time..

Please can someone help with this I don't get it

Comment: `jsonp` -> `json`

Comment: Also check console Netword tab, you're receiving the data from server?

Comment: @Andreas After changing to `json` I now get `Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`

Comment: Check the response if it matches the format expected by select2

Comment: @Andreas it looks like this `{"Total":10,"Results":[{"id":"_spocrawler_24_3595","text":"_spocrawler_24_3595"},{"id":"_spocrwl_319_15489","text":"_spocrwl_319_15489"},{"id":"sp_farm_svc_sponline@domain.com","text":"sp_farm_svc_sponline"},{"id":"_spocrwl_19649","text":"_spocrwl_19649"}]}` which I think is right?

Comment: `Results !== results`

Comment: @Andreas I have tried both `data.results` and `data.Results` and I also tried not calling it with `JSON.parse` but I alwasy get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Andreas suggested in the commments, this was because

```
Results !== results
```

But rather than changing the js, I needed to change the `Results` property in `Select2PagedResult` to **`results`**.

I'm not sure about the `jsonp`, but changing it to `json` seems to have not made any difference, even though the class is called `JsonpResult` in the code.

Comment: _"even though the class is called `JsonpResult` in the code"_ vs. `public JsonResult GetUsers` - Either you're wrong or the code is wrong.

Comment: @Andreas Actually [the sample code](https://github.com/NeilMeredith/Select2Demo/blob/master/Select2Demo/Helpers/JsonpResult.cs) has `JsonpResult` which inherits from `JsonResult`.